# About finding a limit

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measure and $0\leq g(x)\leq 1$ for a.e $x \in [0,1]$. Find the limit 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f(g(x)^n) dx. 
$$

Thanks for any help.

*proof:* Following the hints:

Consider $E_1=\{x: g(x)=1\}$, $E_2=\{x: 0\leq g(x)<1\}$ and $E:=E_1 \cup E_2$. Now, set 
$$
h_n(x):=f(g(x)^n)\cdot \chi_{E}(x)=f(g(x)^n)\cdot \chi_{E_1}(x)+f(g(x)^n)\cdot \chi_{E_2}(x) \quad E_1 \cap E_2 =\emptyset.
$$ 
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} h_n(x)&=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(g(x)^n)\cdot \chi_{E_1}(x)+\lim_{n \to \infty} f(g(x)^n)\cdot \chi_{E_2}(x) \\
&=f(1)\chi_{E_1}(x)+f(0)\chi_{E_2}(x) \quad \textrm{ since $f$ is continuous.}
\end{align*}
Moreover, we see  $ |f(g(x)^n)|\leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ since $f$ attains a maximum on a compact set, in our case $g([0,1])$ is compact.  Hence, we have 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_0^1f(g(x)^n)dx &= \int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} f(g(x)^n)dx \quad \textrm{ By Dominate Convergence Theorem }\\ 
&=\int_0^1 f(1)\cdot \chi_{E_1}(x)dx+ \int_0^1 f(0)\cdot \chi_{E_2}(x)dx \\ 
&=f(1)\int_{E_1}dx+f(0)\int_{E_2}dx\\ 
&=f(1)m(E_1)+f(0)m(E_2) \\ 
\end{align*}

Comment: Hint: $f(g(x)^n)$ converges to $f(1)\mathbf{1}_{\{g=1\}} + f(0)\mathbf{1}_{\{g<1\}}$ a.e. as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: It really matters, thanks a lot.  On the other hand, before passing to the limit, I must show, let's say $h_n(x)=f(g(x)^n)$, is increasing and nonnegative if I apply the monotone convergence theorem, for instance. It is not clear for me. Sorry.

Comment: Apply DCT. The integrand is bounded by the maximum of $|f|$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I really appreciate both of you.